# How to Solve: Insufficient client scope in Python using Spotipy

Tags: python, authentication, oauth, spotify, spotipy

When I try to run cretin modules in Spotipy I get an Insufficient client scope error message. Spotify gives a 403 client error saying "No Token Provided"

Tried multiple modules only a few work such as the current_user() module but others spit back the Insufficient client scope error.

Tried multiple modules only a few work such as the current_user() module but others spit back the Insufficient client scope error.

```
import spotipy
import os
import json
import sys
import webbrowser
import spotipy.util as util
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError


username = sys.argv[0]

try:
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username)

except:
    os.remove(f".cache-{username}")
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username)


spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

albums = spotify.current_user_saved_albums(limit= 100, offset = 0)
userplaylist = spotify.current_user_playlists()
spuser= spotify.current_user()


class spotifyUser:

    def __init__(self, userid, followers, playlist):
        self.userid = userid
        self.followers = followers
        self.playlist = playlist
        self.albums


#list all user playlists
def all_playlists(playlist):

    for r in range(len(playlist['items'])):
        print(playlist['items'][r]['name'])

currentuser = spotifyUser(spuser['display_name'],spuser['followers'] 
['total'], userplaylist)

#all_playlists(currentuser.playlist)
print(albums)
```

When ran results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cesse\PycharmProjects\Spotipy\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 119, in _internal_call
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\cesse\PycharmProjects\Spotipy\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/albums?limit=100&offset=0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Python37/codes/Testspotipy.py", line 20, in <module>
        albums = spotify.current_user_saved_albums(limit= 100, offset = 0)
      File "C:\Users\cesse\PycharmProjects\Spotipy\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 585, in current_user_saved_albums
        return self._get('me/albums', limit=limit, offset=offset)
      File "C:\Users\cesse\PycharmProjects\Spotipy\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 146, in _get
        return self._internal_call('GET', url, payload, kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\cesse\PycharmProjects\Spotipy\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 124, in _internal_call
        headers=r.headers)
    spotipy.client.SpotifyException: http status: 403, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/albums?limit=100&offset=0:
     Insufficient client scope
```

Comment: You'll need the user-library-read scope when you authenticate, not show how's that done in the python example but you'll need to provide that, the error message may refer to this being missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass an extra arg into your prompt for token call, scope as a string separated by spaces:

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope="user-library-read <etc>")
```

[List of available Scopes](https://web.archive.org/web/20210425234118/https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/scopes/)

Comment: Tried and got the exception Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python37/codes/Testspotipy.py", line 13, in <module>
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope=["user-library-read"])
  File "C:\Users\cesse\PycharmProjects\Spotipy\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\util.py", line 50, in prompt_for_user_token
    scope=scope, cache_path=".cache-" + username )
  File "C:\Users\cesse\PycharmProjects\Spotipy\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.scope=self._normalize_scope(scope)

Comment: File "C:\Users\cesse\PycharmProjects\Spotipy\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 225, in _normalize_scope
    scopes = scope.split()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python37/codes/Testspotipy.py", line 16, in <module>
    os.remove(f".cache-{username}")
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '.cache-C:/Python37/codes/Testspotipy.py'

Comment: My bad, it should actually be in string format - I'll update