# Insufficient client scope - Spotify API Golang

Tags: go, spotify

I want to put all the tracks that i have in a slice inside a new playlist but it throws me a `Insufficient client scope` error. This is my code and the client is created with `auth`

```golang
func copyTracksToPlaylist(filteredTracks []spotify.PlaylistItem, client *spotify.Client, ctx context.Context) error {
   newPlaylistID := os.Getenv("NEW_PLAYLIST_ID")

   filteredSongsIDs := extractTracksIDs(filteredTracks)

   return client.ReplacePlaylistTracks(ctx, spotify.ID(newPlaylistID), filteredSongsIDs...)
}
```

I have seen the posible solution in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56173066/how-to-solve-insufficient-client-scope-in-python-using-spotipy) but i don't know how to translate this to the Go's API by zmb3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking at more code in GitHub i found out that the problem was in the declaration of the `auth` that i didn't add the neccesaries scopes. It should look something like this:

```
auth = spotifyauth.New(spotifyauth.WithClientID(os.Getenv("SPOTIFY_ID")), spotifyauth.WithClientSecret(os.Getenv("SPOTIFY_SECRET")), spotifyauth.WithRedirectURL(RedirectUrl), spotifyauth.WithScopes(spotifyauth.ScopeUserReadPrivate, spotifyauth.ScopePlaylistModifyPublic, spotifyauth.ScopePlaylistModifyPrivate, spotifyauth.ScopeUserLibraryRead, spotifyauth.ScopeUserLibraryModify))
```